# JS: Change select option value on being selected with prompt?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've looked around and I don't see this being asked before.

I have a select box, like so:

```
<select onchange="change()">
  <option value="" selected>Option 1</option>
  <option value="30">Option 2</option>
  <option value="90">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

I want to add another option...

```
  <option value="custom">Option 4</option>
```

...that when chosen (clicked) an alert box will popup asking the user to type in a number (in the case 30 or 90 weren't viable options, as in the values of the option's) to replace the value of the option.

```
<script>
function change() {
  if(value == "custom") {
    value = prompt("Please enter a new number:", "60");
  }
}
</script>
```

I wanted to know what the best way to do this is with plain old javascript - I'll use jQuery if I have to.

Any ideas? An example would be great as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at this code. I think this is what you're trying to do:

**HTML**

```
<select id="optionvals" onclick="change()">
  <option value="" selected>Option 1</option>
  <option value="30">Option 2</option>
  <option value="90">Option 3</option>
  <option value="custom">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

**JS**

```
function change() {
  var oItem = document.getElementById('optionvals');
  var value = oItem.options[oItem.selectedIndex].value;
  if(value == "custom") {
    alert("you've clicked b");
    value = prompt("Please enter a new number:", "60");
    oItem.options[oItem.selectedIndex].value = value;
    console.log(oItem.options[oItem.selectedIndex].value)
  }
}
```

What this does is prompt you on the change only if the selected value in the options is `custom`. Then after you choose a custom value, it will rewrite the value of that the `custom` option element to the value you just entered in the prompt. I logged the new value after assigning it to show you that it is working.

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/ng7xvy05/

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you very much! I can't figure JS out for the life of me, I'm enjoying writing PHP very much so more than the format of JS lol

Comment: Could the script find the option based on ID instead of the value, so that it could potentially be changed more than once if needed?

Comment: Yes. Change "value" to "id" in oItem.options[oItem.selectedIndex].value.

Comment: I can't seem to work this out, could you possibly change the fiddle?

Comment: This is the final code I'm using: https://jsfiddle.net/n2pc1658/3/ (just in case anyone looking at the answer is curious)

Answer (score 1):

Your `onchange` event is the appropriate way to handle this. This is mostly a matter of user interface (UX) design though. To do this in the prompt fashion you ought to use `parseFloat`:

```
change() {
  var value = prompt('You\'ve chosen Other. Please enter a value', '60');
  if(value) {
    value = parseFloat(value);
    // apply it to your model
  } else {
    // apply NULL to your model
  }
}
```

From a `UXD` point of view I would use a `typeahead` input. It would autosearch known answers but also allow the user to input their own. This is not standard html so you would need to write this yourself or use jquery. But from a user interface design point of view, prompts suck.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'm not a fan of prompts myself... and I would never use one on the front end of a website. This is just a small tool I'm using to perform calculations that save a lot of time - intended for a few employees, the prompt is the simplest thing I can think of. If I wanted to go crazy I suppose I could create the popup model and create my own input. I also doubt this option will be used very often... either way +1 for the suggestion and thinking about UI/UX.